# jQuery doesn't work in React App.js. Please help beginner's problem

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm not sure why it doesn't show the list when input text. I believe jquery doesn't work in here. I tried to see other posts and import script api and added jQuery.noConflict() as well but it didn't work. I also tried to move around the  position but I believe it should be located in the last part...
I'm just a beginner and trying to figure out and learn. THank you so much!

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import $ from 'jquery'

function App() {
  return (

    <div className="App">

      <div id="listbox">
        <ul id="list">
        </ul>
      </div>
      <input id="inputTxt" />
      <button id="addBtn">Add</button>
      <script type="text/javascript" src='./script.js'>

        type="text/javascript" is important for jquery
      </script>


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

script.js

```
jQuery.noConflict()
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addBtn").click(function () {
      var txt = $("#inputTxt").val();
      if (txt) {
        var listsize = $("#list").children().length;
        alert(listsize % 3);
        if (listsize % 3 == 0) {
          $("#list").append("<li class='red'>" + txt + "</li>");
        } else {
          $("#list").append("<li>" + txt + "</li>");
        }

      }
    });
  });
```

App.css

```
.red{
  color: red;
}
```

It works in codepen and I'm not sure which part I imported incorrectly..

https://codepen.io/disound/pen/vdWrVd

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery together with React? React is not aware of jQuery and at each rerender it will override everything jQuery did.

Comment: JQuery manipulates the DOM. React schedules updates to its own virtual DOM. React and JQuery should never be used together. React has no way of seeing the changes that JQuery makes. So they will constantly be overriding each other.

Answer (score 1):

React and jQuery are both libraries built on top of Javascript and in my oppinion it would be a much greater hassle to make the two "talk" to each other. Instead try to learn just React. Everything you can do with jQuery, you can do with React.

I have made an attempt here to convert your code to pure React and at the same time tried to make it look as close to your own code as possible.
Analyze the code, try to understand what is going on and if you have questions, ask here on Stackoverflow:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [listElements, setListElements] = useState([]);
  const [txt, setTxt] = useState("");

  function handleInput() {
    if (txt) {
      var listsize = listElements.length;
      if (listsize % 3 == 0) {
        setListElements(prev => [...prev, <li key={listsize} className="red">{txt}</li>])
      } else {
        setListElements(prev => [...prev, <li key={listsize}>{txt}</li>])
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <div id="listbox">
        <ul id="list">
          {listElements}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <input id="inputTxt" onChange={e => setTxt(e.target.value)} />
      <button id="addBtn" onClick={handleInput}>Add</button>

    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! I tried to make it work without React and I want to compare two codes to understand each framework more clearly. I will get back here if I have more questions!